# Format complex character string as Date

Tags: r, lubridate

I am working with a dataframe of dates in `R`. The dataframe I have is next:

```
df
                          Date Q
1 Thu Nov 18 16:32:03 COT 2021 1
2 Tue Feb 01 23:28:14 COT 2022 1
3 Wed Feb 02 16:43:15 COT 2022 1
4 Sun Apr 03 22:17:28 COT 2022 1
5 Tue Apr 05 10:47:36 COT 2022 1
6 Thu Jul 01 16:52:52 COT 2021 1
```

With `dput()`:

```
#Dput
df <- structure(list(Date = c("Thu Nov 18 16:32:03 COT 2021", "Tue Feb 01 23:28:14 COT 2022", 
"Wed Feb 02 16:43:15 COT 2022", "Sun Apr 03 22:17:28 COT 2022", 
"Tue Apr 05 10:47:36 COT 2022", "Thu Jul 01 16:52:52 COT 2021"
), Q = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The main issue is about `Date` variable. As you can see it has a very long and complex format. I have tried using `as.Date()` or even `lubridate` but I can not get the code working to format the dates. In the end I would like to have something like this:

```
                          Date Q    NewDate
1 Thu Nov 18 16:32:03 COT 2021 1 2021-11-18
2 Tue Feb 01 23:28:14 COT 2022 1 2022-02-01
3 Wed Feb 02 16:43:15 COT 2022 1 2022-02-02
4 Sun Apr 03 22:17:28 COT 2022 1 2022-04-03
5 Tue Apr 05 10:47:36 COT 2022 1 2022-04-05
6 Thu Jul 01 16:52:52 COT 2021 1 2021-07-01
```

And if it is possible, I would also like to extract the time/hour from the variable `Date` too. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We may use

```
df$NewDate <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S COT %Y")
```

-output

```
df$NewDate
[1] "2021-11-18" "2022-02-01" "2022-02-02" "2022-04-03" "2022-04-05" "2021-07-01
```

If the `COT` part is not constant, remove that substring with `sub` and then apply

```
df$NewDate <- as.Date(sub("\\w+\\s+(\\d{4})$", "\\1", df$Date),
       format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

If we want the time as well

```
datetime <-  as.POSIXct(df$Date, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S COT %Y")
df$NewDate <- as.Date(datetime)
df$Time <- format(datetime, "%T")
```

-output

```
> df
                          Date Q    NewDate     Time
1 Thu Nov 18 16:32:03 COT 2021 1 2021-11-18 16:32:03
2 Tue Feb 01 23:28:14 COT 2022 1 2022-02-02 23:28:14
3 Wed Feb 02 16:43:15 COT 2022 1 2022-02-02 16:43:15
4 Sun Apr 03 22:17:28 COT 2022 1 2022-04-04 22:17:28
5 Tue Apr 05 10:47:36 COT 2022 1 2022-04-05 10:47:36
6 Thu Jul 01 16:52:52 COT 2021 1 2021-07-01 16:52:52
```